# How do you replace a directory with its children?

Tags: unix, command-line, zsh

If I have a directory tree that looks like this:

```
parent/
   child/
      many files
```

What command/commands should I use to quickly make it like this:

```
parent/
   many files
```

Effectively, I just want to remove one level of folder nesting. I don't care about any other files currently in parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you do:

```
cd parent
mv child/* .
rmdir child
```

If you have files beginning with `.` (dot) in the `child/` directory, you have to do

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

in order for the `*` to match them (there are other ways to force this, but setting `dotglob` is the easiest).

If `child/` contains a file or directory named `child`, then you have to either rename that or the directory `parent/child` before the `mv` operation.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
mkdir new
find parent -type f -exec mv {} new/. \;
```

That would work for any depth of directory.

Comment: This will move the immediate children of `parent/`, too, which is not wanted. It will also flatten the entire directory structure, which was not asked for (might or might not be intended). Also, asker wants to move the files into `parent/` and not `new/`.